# How to create a loop in jmeter with different variables

Tags: performance, loops, jmeter

I have the :
var_1=x, var_2=y, var_3=z

I need to create a loop (3), for to check which variable is different to "z"? and if there is a varible different to "z", Get a HTTP request  for each different value.  Somebody can help me! My solution no work!

- -LOOP CONTROLER (3)
- -iF CONTROLER /  Condition   "${__V(VAR_${__counter(,)})}" != "z"
- -HTTP REQUEST / path: /accessweb/${__V(VAR_${__counter(,)})}

Comment: can you please tell us from where did you read the variable? CSV file? output of Regular Expression Extractor?

Comment: Regular Expression Extractor

Comment: does the answer shared by Dmitri worked for you. If not, then I'll try for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 possible problems:

1. You have mismatch between defined and referenced variables. [JMeter Variables are case sensitive (as well as functions and properties)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) so `var_1` and `VAR_1` are totally different variables having different values.

   [image: upper and lower case variables]

   If this is the case you will need to use lower-case `var_` prefix everywhere:

   - `"${__V(var_${__counter(,)})}" != "z"`
   - `/accessweb/${__V(var_${__counter(,)})}`
2. Possible double increment of the __counter, first one in the If Controller and second in the HTTP Request. I would recommend storing the current counter value into an interim JMeter Variable and using this variable instead of the function in the HTTP Request like:

   - `"${__V(VAR_${__counter(,N)})}" != "z"`
   - `/accessweb/${__V(VAR_${N})}`

     [image: Counter reference]

   Alternative way is using [Counter config element](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) instead.